# how to find dynamically loading websites with java program?

Tags: selenium, web-crawler, google-crawlers, domcrawler

I am crawling webpages with the help of jsoup..But it does not work fine for dynamic webpages..In that case i will use selenium for crawling a dynamic site..The problem is that ,how to find the difference between static webpage and dynamic webpage using http response or any html tags in that site?

Comment: Do you have any code to begin with?

Comment: it is not based on the code...i need to know whether we can detect dynamically loading websites with java program ?